# Basic Cross-Domain messaging using postMessage

Tags: javascript, html, cross-domain, postmessage

I am trying to learn basic Cross-Domain messaging and my reference is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage

I hosted 2 html files in IIS:
CrossDomainMessagingDemo/SiteOne/Home.html : used SiteOne folder to be hosted as : `http://localhost:6080`

CrossDomainMessagingDemo/SiteTwo/Home.html : used SiteTwo folder to be hosted as : `http://localhost:6081`

Checked both the urls working in browser i.e. `http://localhost:6080/home.html and http://localhost:6081/home.html`

Contents of my SiteOne/Home.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            var popUp = window.open("http://localhost:6081/home.html");
            popUp.postMessage("The user of bob and the password is 'abcdpass'", "http://localhost:6081");

            function receiveMessage(event){
                console.log(event.data);
            }
            window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        this is in siteOne
        <hr/>
    </body>


</html>
```

Contents of my SiteTwo/Home.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){

            function receiveMessage(event){
                console.log(event.data);
                event.source.postMessage("hi there!, the secret response is 'I am Batman'", event.origin);
            }

            window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        this is on sitetwo
    </body>


</html>
```

The problem is that when i open `http://localhost:6080/home.html` and try to see some console logs in the developer tool, there are no logs. Apparently, the message didn't go through. What am i doing wrong here. i am following the example provided here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage

Comment: Just for a test, try to post a message with origin equal to "*" and see if that will work.

Comment: just tried, didn't work.

Comment: Just for a test, try to run your code on sitetwo "immediately", meaning without the jQuery(document).ready(function(){ ... }); wrapper...

Comment: It's working now :). but hold on.. as per the learning part, i still don't know what was wrong earlier?

Comment: Now try to bring back the jQuery(document).ready(function(){ ... }); wrapper, but just around the window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false); Leave the function receiveMessage out of the wrapper.